# Do we have these kinds of "mean value"?

Tags: statistics, optimization

Let $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ be positive numbers. We want to find a number $x$ such that the sum
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n|x-x_i|
$$
get its minimal value. I know that such $x$ may be not unique. Nevertheless do we have a specific name and any study for such $x$?

Moreover, could we also find a number $y$ such that the sum
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n|\frac{y-x_i}{y}|
$$
get its minimal value? How to find such $y$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first answer is one way of defining the median of the numbers $x_1,\dots,x_n$. When $n$ is odd, this number actually is uniquely determined. When $n$ is even, the median (in this sense) is in general not uniquely determined, which is why we usually teach basic statistics students to calculate it as an average.

You can see this with differentiation: the derivative of $|x-x_i|$ with respect to $x$ is $1$ if $x>x_i$, $-1$ if $x<x_i$. It is not classically defined when $x=x_i$, but it is natural to call it $0$, since $|x|$ is minimized at $0$. If you do this, then you find by setting the derivative equal to zero that the "median" in the sense above is characterized by the same number of $x_i$ being greater and less than it.

You can use the same technique on your second problem: you need to calculate the derivative of $\left | \frac{y-x_i}{y} \right |$ with respect to $y$, sum over $i$, and then set this equal to zero. Setting this up, each term is

$$\text{sign} \left (  \frac{y-x_i}{y} \right ) \frac{y-(y-x_i)}{y^2} = \text{sign} \left ( \frac{y-x_i}{y} \right ) \frac{x_i}{y^2}.$$

Since certainly $y \neq 0$, this reduces to solving

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \text{sign}(y-x_i)x_i=0.$$

Note that because of the discontinuity, this may not be solvable in the usual sense. But we can do the following. Bringing back the factors, we had a derivative of

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \text{sign} \left ( \frac{y-x_i}{y} \right ) \frac{x_i}{y^2}.$$

Suppose the $x$'s are positive for illustration. Then the derivative is positive as $y \to -\infty$ and going to zero there. (So one must make sure that the global minimum is less than $n$, since that can be attained at $\pm \infty$.) Eventually the quantity blows up near $0$, and then decreases. For a while it decreases, and eventually the derivative may jump up to a positive number without ever passing through zero. You'll find the minimum there.

For example, consider the numbers $1,2,4$. Then the derivative is $7/y^2$ until hitting zero, then $-7/y^2$ until it hits $1$, then $-6/y^2$ right at $1$, then $-5/y^2$ immediately after $1$ then $-3/y^2$ right at $2$, then $-1/y^2$ immediately after $2$. Then it jumps to $3/y^2$ right at $4$, so $4$ is actually the minimum.

Answer (score 1):

If you let $X$ be distributed with the empirical distribution of $x_1,\ldots,x_n$, the first problem becomes finding $c$ such that $E[|X-c|]$ is minimized, which is given by the median of $X$ (i.e. the median of $x_1,\ldots,x_n$).

Comment: Thank you! I got it. However the second problem is not that simple, isn't it?

Comment: It is. Your problem is finding $c$ such that $E[|X/c -1|]$ is minimized, which is quite similar. So, you want to find $c$ such that the median of $x_1/c,\ldots,x_n/c$ is 1.